# How to make html layout like my image?

Tags: html, css, layout

How i can define this layout in html to fill all available space in screen?

[image: Layout image]

Comment: This website is not a good place to ask for complete solutions. We are happy to help improve or modify broken code, but unlikely to provide a solution from nothing. That said, you may wish to take a look at the Bootstrap framework to create something like your image. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="width:100%; height:40px; background-color:red"> Top Panel </div>
<div style="width:80%; height:500px; background-color:orange; float:right">Dynamic Panel</div>
<div style="width:20%; height: 500px; background-color:yellow; float:left">Menu Panel</div>
<div style="clear:both">
<div style="width:100%; height:40px; background-color:green">Bottom Panel</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seems to be a newbie.

```
<div> tags will be used four times.
```

first `<div>` will be your header division
second `<div>` will be your navigation area "MENU PANEL"
Third `<div>` will be your main body
And
fourth `<div>` will be your footer.

Use padding property for removing spaces between border and your division
use width and height manually.
Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
HTML:
<div id = 'topPanel'>...CONTENT...</div>
<div id = 'menuPanel'>...CONTENT...</div>
<div id = 'bottomPanel'>...CONTENT...</div>
<div id = 'contentMain'>...CONTENT...</div>

CSS:
#topPanel{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background: //YOUR COLOUR HERE
}

#menuPanel{
position:fixed;
top:60px;
left:0px;
width:20%;
height:100%;
padding-top:60px;
background: //YOUR COLOUR
}

#bottomPanel{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:40%;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background: //YOUR COLOUR
}

#contentMain{
position:fixed;
top:60px;
left:20%;
width:80%;
height:100%;
padding-bottom:60px;
background: //YOUR COLOUR
}
```

Using percent values, rather than full pixel values will allow you to use the full potential of the users screen, because it fills entirely, instead of staying statically positioned.

Good Luck!

P.S. Please ask questions related to code errors, rather than large solutions.